# If we use Linkedlist to deploy the Stack, is there are differernce between stack.push() and stack.addFirst()?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack

Now I am using LinkedList to deploy the Stack as:

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new LinkedList();
```

If I want to simtulate the Push operation I will do :

```
        stack.addFirst(a);
```

[image]

Since I am using linkedlist, Element 4 is the top of the stack and 1 is the bottom of the stack.

Now, what's the difference between ***stack.push and stack.addFirst()*** in this case?

Will they have same behaviour??

Comment: Try both and see if there's a difference? This is a good opportunity to do some science: Hypothesize what might happen, try it and see whether it verifies your hypothesis.

Comment: They are same, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html):

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy `Stack` class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque. Stack methods are precisely equivalent to `Deque` methods as indicated in the table below:
>
> | Stack Method | Equivalent Deque Method |
> | --- | --- |
> | push(e) | addFirst(e) |
> | pop() | removeFirst() |
> | peek() | peekFirst() |